# Web Apple Icons

Tags: html, image

Well, There a lot of articles out there on Apple Icons but none really give you a clear cut answer on how to make your icons with a border.

Here is the way I am defining in my html:

```
<link href="http://www.sample.com/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png" rel="image_src">
```

Here is what I have now(sample):

- 129px x 129px
- Border Radius: 26px
- Solid Background

What is the proper way to get a icon with a border or inner glow on all apple devices. This is kinda hard for me to test as I do not own an Apple device.

Should I have a solid background? 
What border radius?
Any special way to turn off apples auto round?
etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this [Icon Reference](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/iconreference/) helpful when making an icon with a border around it. It will tell you the various border-radii. Apple also has [a document](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) on configuring each icon size.

According to [Apple's icon design guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html), you should have a solid background with no transparency. The border radius that iOS applies is not changeable, it's part of the aesthetic.

You mention that you don't have an iOS device to test on, but if you have a Mac you can still use the iOS Simulator to see what your icon will look like.

Comment: Thanks, the icon reference does help. The reason I did my icon the way i did is because I tried to copy what deviantART had and I assume they had a correct way of doing it: http://st.deviantart.net/minish/widgets/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png - I do not have a mac either. If anyone could test out the sample icon i provided on the OP on the devices and post a result pic, that would be great!

Answer (score 2):

Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14

Comment: I have looked at this many a times. Doesn't really help for what I am asking. Needs to be more specific

Comment: What are you talking about read it: it tells you that it will round the corners and add the white highlight for you unless you specify a specific image name.

Comment: It rounds no matter what and I already have it as apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png which gets rid of gloss.

Comment: I don't think you can stop apple from rounding it off if I recall, my mistake